# como puedo mostrar una imagen en el data grill, sale system.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: windows-forms, imagen, datagridview

Estoy tratando de mostrar en el datagrill imagenes y me sale system.Drawing.Bitmap, no logoro hacer mostrar las iamgenes en la celda 6, tengo las iamgenes añadidas a las propiedades del proyecto.

```
 private void buttonProductos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewProducto.Rows.Clear();
        Connection.Sentence("select* from Producto");
        SqlDataReader reader2 = Connection.Query();
        int n;// renglon
        Image img1 = Properties.Resources.cocacola;
        Image img2 = Properties.Resources.Fanta_pg;
        Image img3 = Properties.Resources.Sprite;
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            n = dataGridViewProducto.Rows.Add();   // esto nos da el nuemero de Row que creamos, tenemos que tener las columnas creadas
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = reader2[0].ToString();
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = reader2[1].ToString();
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = reader2[2].ToString();
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = reader2[3].ToString();
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = reader2[4].ToString();
            dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = reader2[5].ToString();
            if (reader2[0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = img1;
            }
            if (reader2[0].ToString() == "2")
            {
                dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = img2;
            }
            if (reader2[0].ToString() == "3")
            {
                dataGridViewProducto.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = img3;
            }
        }
        reader2.Close();
    }
```

ALguna manera de convertir el system.Drawing.Bitmap a imagen que se pueda ver en el datagrill

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo tienes que comprobar que la columna 6 sea del tipo DataGridViewImageColumn. Segundo al final de cargar los datos para que quepa la imagen tendras que meter en el codigo al iniciar (solo hace falta una vez):

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[6] as DataGridViewImageColumn;
        imageColumn.ImageLayout= DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;//esta es la que te interesa
```

No sé cuál es el motivo, pero no hace caso si lo metes desde el diseñador

Comment: gracias, lo intentare